# High latency with google sheets api calls

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-developers-console

I'm having very high latencies (5min) on google sheets append values requests. This is starting to happen more and more. As I have been doing the same requests for months (and same volume) I don't think it is because of my inputs.

Checking google support they suggested to create a topic here. Not sure if a google engineer will comment or if some other end users are experiencing the same problem?

In the charts you see a lot of errors, these are the errors I get: "append_sheet: googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError". So nothing useful :s.

Greetings,

PJ

[image: google developers console]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your code to see what's being done?

Comment: Hi @AMolina, I'm doing regular sheet appends. With around 2500 rows per append. However since this morning I'm seeing lower latencies when I'm only appending smaller sheets (with less than 50k records). I'm guessing Google is having a hard time appending big sheets (as maybe he needs to load everything in memory before adding something?)

Comment: How are you running the code? the image you shared makes it seem it gets run constantly, do you have it on a timed trigger? Also, looking at [the method's documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), you could be overreaching where to write the data because of the size of your sheets, if it keeps creating new rows every time (and it's run as often as it seems), you could be reaching limits.